# CGAL::do_intersect() on Polyhedron_3

Tags: computational-geometry, cgal

I'm using CGAL::do_intersect() on Polygon_2 types and it works very well :

```
bool Polygon_ac::isIntersecting(FormVirtual* secondForm){

return CGAL::do_intersect(*dynamic_cast<Polygon_2*>(this),
                          *dynamic_cast<Polygon_2*>(secondForm));
```

}
Now I would detect intersection but between Polyhedron_3, it does not work :

Error in stl_iterator_base_types.h...

**Is it supposed to work or is there another way to achieve this test ?**

Gilles

Answer (score 1):

It is not supposed to work. However, there is an undocumented function in `CGAL/intersection_of_Polyhedra_3.h`

```
template <typename Polyhedron, typename OutputIterator>
OutputIterator
intersection_Polyhedron_3_Polyhedron_3(
  const Polyhedron& P,
  const Polyhedron& Q,
  OutputIterator out);
```

that puts in `out` `std::vector<Point_3>` representing intersection polylines between `P` and `Q`. With a counting output iterator, you can easily do the predicate you want.

Comment: Hello,
can you give me more informations !
this makes errors :
CGAL::intersection_Polyhedron_3_Polyhedron_3(*dynamic_cast<Polyhedron*>(this),
                                                 *dynamic_cast<Polyhedron*>(secondForm),std::back_inserter(intR));

Comment: You need to define an output iterator or you can try to use `CGAL::Counting_output_iterator` defined in `CGAL/iterator.h`

Comment: Hello,
I just cannot make it work. I'm a bit newbies with these outputiterators !
Is it possible to get an example ??

Comment: `std::size_t nb_polylines=0; CGAL::Counting_output_iterator out(&nb_polylines);` Plug `out` in the function and then check whether `nb_polylines` is different from 0

Comment: It works now ! Thanks for help and nice week-end...
Gilles